# How to return the value of a while loop counter

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, return

I want to return the counter of the while loops, i and b after every loop repetition to use in another function. I haven't found anything related to returning these values.

```
def dis(reps, towards, back):
    t = 0  # move towards t times
    b = 0  # move back b times
    i = 0  # repetitions
    n =  1 # counts every step
    while i < reps:
        while t < towards:
            do_something()
            i += 1
            n +=1
        while b < back:
            do_something()
            n += 1
            b += 1
        t = 0
        b = 0
        i += 1
```

I thought of adding another variable like counter_towards and counter_back and add a value each time but that would not fix my problem since I still would have to return these values every rep. Adding the related functions to a class might work aswlel but that would be lot of work and i thought there might be an easy answer to this question.

Comment: The whole point of `return` is to provide an exit condition to your function.
What you're describing sounds more like a class method accessing and incrementing the values of the class property.
Consider the object oriented approach, since this is what python was built for.

Answer (score 1):

You have to watch on python Generators. Here's [a link](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/)!